# Is it possible to register wasm file like javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, webassembly

I have a javascript file that calls a wasm file, when I register the javascritpt somewhere in the script, it fetch the file from the wrong location.
What's the best practice to solve this problem?

Here is what's going on:

```js
$this->registerJsFile('@web/folder/file.js', ['position' => \app\components\View::POS_END]);
```

it suppose to get the wasm file from /folder/ but instead it grabbing it from /folder2/folder3/wasmfile.wasm

Comment: you should add some info. Console output, errors messages, etc.

Comment: You haven't got `folder2` in your code at all. Please provide exact values.

Comment: I'm using yii2, the script is generating html files like this:
Domain/play/gamename/
The js and wasm files are located in : Domain/ps/
When the js file fetched, it acts like it's been fetched from: Domain/play/gamename/ and when it tries to fetch the wasm file it can't find it because it's basically not inside /gamename/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to convert common alias `@web` into a string. It is not done automatically in `registerJsFile`.

```
$this->registerJsFile(Yii::getAlias('@web/folder/file.js'), 
    ['position' => \app\components\View::POS_END]);
```

It is a known problem, you can see one [rejected pull request here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/2133).

Comment: It's not "known problem" - aliases are being converted since 2.0.0 (see this [fix by Cebe](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/commit/bc9b62c31402645493027fdc36381870791aaf39))